# allign the hover list menu starting from top list item height

Tags: html, css, menu

in my current menu drop down , I have a sub menu having 5 list items

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-list">
                <li>Menu Item 1
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>sub Menu Item 1</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 2</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 3</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>Menu Item 2
                 <ul class="submenu">
                    <li>sub Menu Item 1</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 2</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 3</li>
                    <li>sub Menu Item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Menu Item 3</li>
                <li>Menu Item 4</li>
                <li>Menu Item 5</li>
            </ul>
```

CSS

```
    #menu-list
{
    background:inherit;

    }
    #menu-list li
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        border: 1px solid black;
         position:fixed;

        }
    #menu-list li:hover 
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        visibility:visible;
        }
    #menu-list .submenu
    {
        position:fixed;
        margin: -25px 0px 0px 100px;
        z-index: 50;
        visibility:hidden;    
            }

      #menu-list li:hover .submenu
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        visibility:visible;
        position:fixed;

        }
```

I wish that the submenu starts from same height(top) as parent menu , please share some hints , thanks

like ,on mouse hover

```
list 1 --> sub-1
list 2     sub-2
list 3     sub-3

list 1     sub-1
list 2 --> sub-2
list 3     sub-3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2HQze/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, first of all you need to overwrite position value of `#menu li ul li` from relative to static, like:

```
#menu li ul li {
 position: static;
}
```

Then you need to give `position: relative` to `#menu li ul`, like:

```
#menu li ul {
 position: relative;
}
```

And finally give `position: absolute` to submenu at hover, like:

```
#menu-list li:hover .submenu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 25px;
}
```

Check out the [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanz/2HQze/4/).

Comment: Top ? isnt a temporary solution , it might not work on other machines

Comment: Its relative to `#menu li ul`. so it won't be disturbed somewhere else.

Comment: no it didn't , its not acting relative to #menu li ul , kindly reporduce it in an html file to confirm

Comment: Yeah i confirmed now. Check it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanz/2HQze/8/show/) as html file.

Answer (score 0):

Added `top:158px;` to `#menu-list .submenu`

http://jsfiddle.net/2HQze/1/

Comment: I think its a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2HQze/2/

```
.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:-30px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2HQze/3/

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
left:-1px;
top:-7px;
    z-index:10;
```

}